# Get subroutine to return value

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

the workflow is to build a AWS IAM user access key object. Then push to a global array. And finally print the array. The issue is where a subroutine is called within a forEach, to get the users access keys. The access keys are returned in a callback, then pushed to the global array, but the values never make it back to the final statement to print the global array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here are the two functions:

```
// Build IAM user profile, then make subroutine to get their access keys 
function analyseReport(iam, report, des, ac) {

    new csv(report, {
        header: true
    }).forEach(function(object) {

        accumulateSize++
        var iamObj = {};

        iamObj.account = ac;
        iamObj.account_name = des;
        iamObj.user = object.user;

        if (object.access_key_1_active == 'true') {

            iamObj.access_key_1 = 'null';
            iamObj.access_key_1_active = object.access_key_1_active;
            iamObj.access_key_1_last_rotated = object.access_key_1_last_rotated;
            iamObj.access_key_1_last_used_date = object.access_key_1_last_used_date;
            iamObj.access_key_1_last_used_service = object.access_key_1_last_used_service;
        }

        if (object.access_key_2_active == 'true') {

            iamObj.access_key_2 = 'null';
            iamObj.access_key_2_active = object.access_key_2_active;
            iamObj.access_key_2_last_rotated = object.access_key_2_last_rotated;
            iamObj.access_key_2_last_used_date = object.access_key_2_last_used_date;
            iamObj.access_key_2_last_used_service = object.access_key_2_last_used_service;
        }

        if (iamObj.access_key_1_active == 'true' || iamObj.access_key_2_active == 'true') {

            var params = {
                UserName: object.user
            };

            // Get access keys for user
            iam.listAccessKeys(params, function(err, data) {

                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                else {
                    appendKeysCounter++;

                    // Append the access key to the user object, then push to global array
                    appendKeys(data, iamObj,function(returnValue){

                        userAry.push(returnValue);

                    });
                };
            });
        }
    });

    if (appendKeysCounter == 0) {

        console.log('Final report size : ', userAry.length);
        console.log('Final report : ');
        userAry.forEach(item => console.log(item));
    }
}


function appendKeys(data, iamObj, callback) {

    appendKeysCounter--;

    data.AccessKeyMetadata.forEach(function(keysObj) {

        if (keysObj.Status == 'Active') {

            if (isDate(iamObj.access_key_1_last_rotated)) {

                // Compare the creation date with the last rotated date
                if ((new Date(keysObj.CreateDate)).toISOString() === (new Date(iamObj.access_key_1_last_rotated)).toISOString()) {

                    iamObj.access_key_1 = keysObj.AccessKeyId;
                }
            }

            if (isDate(iamObj.access_key_2_last_rotated)) {

                // Compare the creation date with the last rotated date
                if ((new Date(keysObj.CreateDate)).toISOString() === (new Date(iamObj.access_key_2_last_rotated)).toISOString()) {

                    iamObj.access_key_2 = keysObj.AccessKeyId;
                }
            }

        }
    });

    callback(iamObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update

The solution has been to add iamObj.access_key_1 and iamObj.access_key_2 with null values when creating the initial iamObj and push to a user array. Then get the access keys for the user and push them to a key array. The access keys request is encapsulated in a promise array. Once it returns in the promise.all section, both the user and key arrays are full and ready for the final step, of comparing the user array key creation date and key array key creation date. Where a match exists, then update the iamObj.access_key_1 or iamObj.access_key_2 field with the access key value. Finally write the user array to file.

Refinements - the for each loops could be replaced with for loops that break once the match is found, this would save a considerable amount of processing time.

Here is the code -

```
// Get each username, is their key active, when was the active key last used
function analyseReport(iam, report, des, ac) {

    // Mark each call out
    callCount--;

    new csv(report, {
        header: true
    }).forEach(function(object) {

        // accumulateSize++
        var iamObj = {};

        iamObj.account = ac;
        iamObj.account_name = des;
        iamObj.user = object.user;

        if (object.access_key_1_active == 'true') {

            iamObj.access_key_1 = 'null';
            iamObj.access_key_1_active = object.access_key_1_active;
            iamObj.access_key_1_last_rotated = object.access_key_1_last_rotated;
            iamObj.access_key_1_last_used_date = object.access_key_1_last_used_date;
            iamObj.access_key_1_last_used_service = object.access_key_1_last_used_service;
        }

        if (object.access_key_2_active == 'true') {

            iamObj.access_key_2 = 'null';
            iamObj.access_key_2_active = object.access_key_2_active;
            iamObj.access_key_2_last_rotated = object.access_key_2_last_rotated;
            iamObj.access_key_2_last_used_date = object.access_key_2_last_used_date;
            iamObj.access_key_2_last_used_service = object.access_key_2_last_used_service;
        }

        if (iamObj.access_key_1_active == 'true' || iamObj.access_key_2_active == 'true') {

            userAry.push(iamObj);

            // Get key data
            var params = {
                UserName: object.user
            };

            promiseAry.push(iam.listAccessKeys(params).promise().then(function(data) {

                data.AccessKeyMetadata.forEach(function(keysObj) {
                    keyAry.push({
                        userName: keysObj.UserName,
                        accessKeyId: keysObj.AccessKeyId,
                        status: keysObj.Status,
                        createDate: keysObj.CreateDate
                    });
                });

            }).catch((err) => {

            }));
        }
    });

    // Wait for all account calls to finish
    if (callCount == 0) {

        // Wait for all keys to return
        Promise.all(promiseAry).then(() => {
            // Logic - itterate user and key arrays
            // Where username maches, and keyAry active, and dates match
            // Save access key to user array

            userAry.forEach(function(userObj, index) {

                keyAry.forEach(keyObj => {

                    if (userObj.user == keyObj.userName &&
                        keyObj.status == 'Active') {

                        if (isDate(userObj.access_key_1_last_rotated)) {

                            if ((new Date(userObj.access_key_1_last_rotated)).toISOString() === (new Date(keyObj.createDate)).toISOString()) {

                                userAry[index].access_key_1 = keyObj.accessKeyId;
                            } // dates match

                        } // is a date

                        if (isDate(userObj.access_key_2_last_rotated)) {

                            if ((new Date(userObj.access_key_2_last_rotated)).toISOString() === (new Date(keyObj.createDate)).toISOString()) {

                                userAry[index].access_key_2 = keyObj.accessKeyId;
                            } // dates match

                        } // is a date

                    } //user and active
                }); //keyAry.forEach

            }); //userAry.forEach
            // userAry.forEach(item => console.log(item));
            writeToFile(userAry);
        }); //Promise.all

    }
```